# Routing all requests to another php file excepts those originaly *.php by mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website contains profiles of users.
I want the users to access their profiles by a link like:

```
www.mysite.com/username
```

Users can access their categories page by a link like:

```
www.mysite.com/username/categories
```

and also can access a specific category by a link like:

```
www.mysite.com/categories/5
```

where `username` is a variable, `categories` is a constant string in the url and `5` is a variable number representing the category id.

I know that can be done in the .htaccess file, but how can I do this ?

Comment: check into the `-f` and `-d` tests in mod_rewriter. you can use them to exclude files that truly exist and aren't just virtual paths.

Comment: I'm new to .htaccess, so, give me example if you have.

Comment: it has nothing to do with .htaccess. that's just one place you can put the mod_rewrite stuff. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: what is the filename of your php script that has to handle the requests?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pass

`/mohamed` to `/users.php?name=mohamed`,

`/mohamed/categories` to `/categories.php?username=mohamed`,

`/categories/5` to `/categories.php?id=5`

Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$ users.php?name=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/categories$ categories.php?username=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)$ categories.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

`!-f` flag means that if you request an existing filename, it's url won't be rewritten

Comment: Ok, thats exactly what i want and it redirected correctly, but when i use `/mohamed/categories` or `/mohamed/categories/5` its redirected but no images,css or javascripts loaded, only html. What is the problem?

Comment: Images and other files have nothing to do with the above rewrites, since filenames are not rewrited (`-!f`).
If you have an image e.x. `www.mysite.com/images/img5.png` it will be accessable with that url.
Maybe you try to access images as if they were rewritten like `www.mysite.com/categories/....png`?